# Why is my "done" channel closing randomly?

Tags: go, channel

I built the following go code.

The idea is to build a done channel and a generator that generates a channel of int.
Link them in a 2 stage pipe 
chanNumbers := pipeb(done, pipea(done, gen(done)))

After some seconds, cancel the done channel.
I expect to see the generator and two stage of the pipe to cancel and return, but the text "PipeX is terminating now" only appears randomly and I really do not understand why.
Would someone have an idea?

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func gen(done <-chan interface{}) <-chan int {
    ret := make(chan int)
    cx := 0

    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case <-done:
                fmt.Println("**Generator Terminates now")
                time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
                fmt.Println("**Generator has terminated now")
                close(ret)
                return
            case ret <- cx:
                fmt.Printf("Gen : we push %d \n", cx)
                cx = cx + 1
            }
        }
    }()
    fmt.Println("Generator has created and returned its channel")
    return ret
}

func pipea(done <-chan interface{}, in <-chan int) <-chan int {
    ret := make(chan int)

    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case <-done:
                fmt.Println("**pipeA terminates")
                time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
                fmt.Println("**pipeA has terminated now")
                close(ret)
                return
            case tmp, ok := (<-in):
                if ok {
                    fmt.Printf("pipeA : we push %d \n", tmp)
                    ret <- tmp
                } else {
                    in = nil
                }
            }
        }
    }()
    return ret
}

func pipeb(done <-chan interface{}, in <-chan int) <-chan int {
    ret := make(chan int)

    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case <-done:
                fmt.Println("**pipeB terminates")
                time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
                fmt.Println("**pipeB has terminated now")
                close(ret)
                return
            case tmp, ok := (<-in):
                if ok {
                    fmt.Printf("pipeB : we push %d \n", tmp)
                    ret <- tmp
                } else {
                    in = nil
                }
            }
        }
    }()
    return ret
}

func main() {
    done := make(chan interface{})

    chanNumbers := pipeb(done, pipea(done, gen(done)))
    go func() {
        time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
        close(done)
    }()

forloop:
    for {
        select {
        case n := <-chanNumbers:
            fmt.Printf("Received in main element : %d\n", n)
        case <-done:
            break forloop
        }
    }

    //end of the main program
    fmt.Println("Sleeping some seconds before termiating")
    time.Sleep(8 * time.Second)
    fmt.Println("exit...")
}
```

Comment: nit-pick, the `done` channel usually is of type `chan struct{}`. An empty struct is, by the language spec, defined to be 0 bytes in size, and it makes it clear that the channel is used for signalling, and not actual data communication. A channel of type `<-chan interface{}` could be mistaken for a channel you use to pass on data you're _"done"_ with (eg is ready to be stored or something)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have four go-routines running:

1. `gen`, your generator, writing to an unbuffered output channel until `done`
2. `pipeA`, reading from `gen`, writing to an unbuffered output channel until `done`
3. `pipeB`, reading from `pipeA`, writing to an unbuffered output channel until `done`
4. `main`, reading from `pipeB` until `done`

Now when you close `done`, it totally depends on the order in which the go-routines see that.

If `main` is the first to see that `done` is closed, it will break the for-loop and stop consuming from `pipeB`. But if `pipeB` is still trying to write to the output channel (`ret <- tmp`), it will block there; so it will never get to the `<- done` part.

There are two options to fix this:

1. Only listen to `done` in your generator, and have the other go-routines use `for n := range in { }`.
2. Put your sending logic in a `select` as well so your generator and pipes can detect when `done` is closed.

Alternatively, you might want to use buffered output channels, but even then this problem can still occur.

Comment: Thank you publysher. ! this is a perfect answer

Comment: @totofgo you should accept the answer to close it out.